How to have a pool of Python tasks wait for a wake up event
I have created a pool of Python processes with the multiproccessing.pool function, any of which performs similar work. This is to have more work done simultaneously.
I would like all of the tasks to wait on one event/signal/semafore or other object that has the tasks sleeping until signaled. They will perform their work then go back to sleep waiting on that event to trigger again.
Other tasks in the program will trigger the event when they have work that needs to be performed.
I am not sure what I can use for event posting by other tasks when they need work to be performed. I am not sure how to have these tasks wait on that signal.
Using Pool() the tasks are different processes, but they all need to wake up from a common signal of some sort.

This sounds more like you want to have a queue where "other tasks" can throw in work and worker processes take them over or wait if there's no work.

Yes this is for something like a queue. There is actually a set of work structures being placed in a database and these tasks are pulling work off that database. Whenever new work is added to the database, it would trigger an event so one of the available tasks can handle the work.

That is what the queue does even without events.

One solution is to not use a multiprocessing.pool.Pool to create the pool and instead create our own pool implementation using explicit daemon processes. This allows us more easily to assign to each child process its own multiprocessing.JoinableQueue instance that will be used to awaken the particular process. When the child process has completed doing whatever it needs to accomplish after being awaken, it can signal this completion back to the main process by calling the task_done method on its assigned queue. Meanwhile the main process will only block if some new event occurs that should trigger awakening the child processes again but the child processes have not completed what it needed to do after the last time it was awakened:
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue
import time

POOL_SIZE = 4

def worker(queue):
    while True:
        queue.get()
        # Emulate having to do something:
        time.sleep(.5)
        print(f'Done at {time.time()} and waiting for next awakening.')
        queue.task_done()  # Show we have finished

def other_worker(queues):
    wait_for_child_processes_to_finish = False

    # repeat 3 times and then return:
    for _ in range(3):
        # Continue doing something until the next time we need to
        # awaken the child processes. We emulate this for demo purposes
        # by just sleeping for a second.
        time.sleep(1)

        # Do we need to first wait for child processes to complete
        # wahtever they needed to do after having been awakened?
        if wait_for_child_processes_to_finish:
            # Wait for previous awakenings to complete:
            for queue in queues:
                queue.join()

        # Re-awaken the child processes:
        for queue in queues:
            queue.put(None)  # It doesn't matter what we put

        wait_for_child_processes_to_finish = True

    if wait_for_child_processes_to_finish:
        for queue in queues:
            queue.join()

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    queues = [JoinableQueue() for _ in range(POOL_SIZE)]
    # daemon processes:
    processes = [
        Process(target=worker, args=(queues[i],), daemon=True)
        for i in range(POOL_SIZE)
    ]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    other_worker(queues)

Prints:
Done at 1726922097.3293746 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922097.3300514 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922097.3300514 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922097.330555 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922098.332175 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922098.3329866 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922098.3340275 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922098.3340275 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922099.332767 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922099.3334436 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922099.3334436 and waiting for next awakening.
Done at 1726922099.3339515 and waiting for next awakening.

If it is okay to signal to the child processes that there is something for them to do without first having to wait for them to complete what they were already working on, then just code other_worker as follows (it is not clear from the problem description which approach is requred):
def other_worker(queues):
    wait_for_child_processes_to_finish = False

    # repeat 3 times and then return:
    for _ in range(3):
        # Continue doing something until the next time we need to
        # awaken the child processes. We emulate this for demo purposes
        # by just sleeping for a second.
        time.sleep(1)

        # Re-awaken the child processes:
        for queue in queues:
            queue.put(None)  # It doesn't matter what we put

        wait_for_child_processes_to_finish = True

    if wait_for_child_processes_to_finish:
        for queue in queues:
            queue.join()

